# React : how to get input value from one component to make the ajax call in another component?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, variables, react-router

I am building a movie search React app using themoviedb.org API. in order to an make ajax call to pull the list of movies I need to get input value as a variable and feed to the url, but not sure how to fetch a value that belongs to another component.

I've made an extensive online search, but they mainly refer to the case when it happens inside the same component, and using ref is discouraged.

So what would be the best way (or at least most common or the simplest way) to fetch the input value variable from one component to pass down to another and attach to the end of url, while:
1) Keeping global space clean
2) Organizing the entire app in 'React way' 
3) Keeping components decoupled
?
Would React Router necessary in this case?

```
   import React from 'react';
   import './App.css';
   import axios from 'axios';


class SearchForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }


  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    console.log("state value is " + this.state.value);

    var searchValue = this.movieName.value;
    console.log("ref value is "+ searchValue)

    event.preventDefault();
  }


  render() {

    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input className="movieName" type="text" ref={(input) => { this.movieName = input; }} value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />

        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        <h1>{this.state.value}</h1>
      </form>
    );
  }
}



class App extends NameForm{  /* I am extending NameForm to get access to input value, but probably coupling components too tight */
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state ={
        movie:[]
      };
    }



componentDidMount() { 


  let searchInput = "land"; /* This should be from SearchForm's input value */


let sortByPop = "&sort_by=popularity.desc";
let requestUrl = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=f8c4016803faf5e7f424abe98a04b8d9&query=' + searchInput + sortByPop;

  axios.get(requestUrl).then(response => {
      this.setState({movie: response.data.results})
  });



}

render() {

 let baseImgURL = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185_and_h278_bestv2";
 let posterImgPath = this.state.movie.map(movie => movie.poster_path);


 let posterLink = baseImgURL + posterImgPath;

  return(

      <div className="App">
        <Header />    
       <SearchForm />   

   <div> 
          {this.state.movie.map(movie =>
           <div className="movieTitle">
           <div className="movieCard">
           <img className="posterImg" src= {`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185_and_h278_bestv2/${movie.poster_path}`} alt={movie.title} />
           <div className="searchFilmTitles" key={movie.id}>{movie.title}</div>
           </div>
           </div>
           )} 
      </div>

   </div>
  )
}

}


export default App;
```

Comment: simple(not really) awnswer: you need some data-flow managment like: flux or redux. Then you will call actions, and do all AJAX calls in this actions, and then, actions will dispatch to the Store - that will change data for needed component.

Comment: You should pass a function to the `SearchForm` component so that the parent can update its state accordingly. In this case, it looks like `SearchForm` should have a prop `onSearch` provided by the parent component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`componentDidMount` get called only once when your component get attached to the page. So it's not the correct place to call you search API. Instead, you should call it every time when the user clicks 'submit' button. For that, you need to bubble `handleSubmit` trigger to App component by passing a callback method as a prop to SearchForm component. Also, you don't need to use `ref` as you already have search text in your `state`.

**SearchForm**

```
class SearchForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }


  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if(this.props.onSubmit && typeof this.props.onSubmit === "function"){
      this.props.onSubmit(this.state.value);
    }
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input className="movieName" type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        <h1>{this.state.value}</h1>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

**App**

```
class App extends React.Component {  /* I'm not sure why you extends NameForm and what NameForm does */
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      movie:[]
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(value) {
    let searchInput = value // you get the value of movieName input here

    let sortByPop = "&sort_by=popularity.desc";
    let requestUrl = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=f8c4016803faf5e7f424abe98a04b8d9&query=' + searchInput + sortByPop;

    axios.get(requestUrl).then(response => {
        this.setState({movie: response.data.results})
    });
  }

  render() {

    let baseImgURL = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185_and_h278_bestv2";
    let posterImgPath = this.state.movie.map(movie => movie.poster_path);
    let posterLink = baseImgURL + posterImgPath;
    // I'm not sure why use need above code as you don't use it anywhere

    return(
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <SearchForm onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}/>   
      <div> 
        {this.state.movie.map(movie =>
         <div className="movieTitle">
         <div className="movieCard">
         <img className="posterImg" src= {`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185_and_h278_bestv2/${movie.poster_path}`} alt={movie.title} />
         <div className="searchFilmTitles" key={movie.id}>{movie.title}</div>
         </div>
         </div>
         )} 
      </div>
     </div>
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: That works perfectly - thanks! Just on the side note, using flux or redux would be good in a case like this as others suggested? Or it wouldn't be necessary but would help in scalability in a long run?

Comment: You're welcome. In this case, I don't see any advantage of using flux or redux as we can simply do it just using react. But if your state needs to be shared between multiple components then it makes sense to use such a state management library.